# What can I do if nothing is supported on IE?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have an arrow function that was working perfectly on Chrome/Firefox but I also need it working on IE11, and I don't know what more to do.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) you can see that the arrow functions aren't supported on IE11, so I tried to change my code from ES6 to ES5 [here](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Cstage-0&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=PIIwVgpgxgLgdBAdjATgSwgZwBRQIYA2SAJnipgJRwBmA9igKJ5QAW22A2gNYQCeANAAIAboQC6FQQF4AfIIDeAWABQASFCRYCZOizZRBKnUbM2nHrzxCDeCdLnzVK1arTVsFvFKkAiNMR8KJTUXAFs8NAJpEUI8AG5nVQBfRLcPPi9fAAd0cJReQOCXVQBhQgBJABFo8MiEkKTBJsFnJIp6trjBIA) because I read that doing this could solve the problems (on the link you can also check my code :) for removing the arrow functions.

Object.entries isn't supported either, and I'm still needing it.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

So I tried to use the polyfill of the link above but it uses Reflect which isn't supported either. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect

Any ideas? I'm really lost with IE11 dev.
PD: The code is still working on Chrome/Firefox.

Comment: You want a _transpiler_ that translates your ES6 code to “oldschool” JS that older browsers will understand.

Comment: You've identified what you need to do: Use features that are supported. Did you have a *specific* problem? (It sounds like you could turn this into a question about how to reproduce `Object.entries` in ES5, but as it stands it is poorly defined and too broad).

Comment: If you want to support older browsers, you have to write code that works in older browser. All the new methods in ES6 can be written in some other way that will make your code work in older browsers.

Comment: Maybe look for [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: Why are you using features that aren't even part of the current ECMAScript (2017) specification and expect them to work in a browser that was released 3 ECMAScript versions ago? It should not be difficult to write your own polyfill for Object.entries.

Comment: I know that, the thing is that I don't know of any other way to do it. Thats what Im asking for, a solution for this which is IE11 compatible

Comment: Do you only have one arrow function ("*I have an arrow function…*") or are there many of them?

Comment: I only had one, and you can check it [here](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Cstage-0&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=PIIwVgpgxgLgdBAdjATgSwgZwBRQIYA2SAJnipgJRwBmA9igKJ5QAW22A2gNYQCeANAAIAboQC6FQQF4AfIIDeAWABQASFCRYCZOizZRBKnUbM2nHrzxCDeCdLnzVK1arTVsFvFKkAiNMR8KJTUXAFs8NAJpEUI8AG5nVQBfRLcPPi9fAAd0cJReQOCXVQBhQgBJABFo8MiEkKTBJsFnJIp6trjBIA), but the problem is now solved :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is naive implementation of Object.entries.
It works well for all examples in https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

```
Object.entries = Object.entries || function(obj) {
   return Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) {
       return [k, obj[k]];
   });
};
```

Comment: Did you read my question? On the same link you passed me says clearly Internet Explorer -> No Support   I tried but didn't work

Comment: I did not understand you. My implementation does not uses Reflect. Please try it and see whether it works.

Comment: it is pure ecmascript 5 implementation so it should work in IE11 (btw I checked it in IE11 and it do work). Do not know what you are doing but you are probably wrong. I am giving up becuase of your attitude.

Comment: @IXTRUnai did you read the answer ? It allready applies a polyfill for browsers that dont support "entries". [He uses keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) as allready mentioned in the comments of the question. Still no answer, that it works for you or not.

Comment: Holy shit, sry. It's true, It's working. I don't know what I did before. Thx and sorry about my attitude, I've been with this thing too much time.

Comment: @IXTRUnai answer was allready in the comments after six minutes :-P There you go.

Answer (score 1):

[babel](https://babeljs.io/) with [babel preset env](https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env) would be the way to go.

This way you could just list the browsers you intend to support and then babel will only transpile (convert pieces of your code to ES5) parts of your code that need to be converted to support all your browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use several solution to implement support new ES8+ features in old browsers.

Full-circuit solution can be based on **Webpack** with **babel-transformers** and set of **polyfills**, which also called **shims**. You can see stereotypical configuration in `create-react-app` or `next.js` boilerplate.

More that, if you have no IE11 installation on development machine, you can run E2E/functional tests on **SauseLabs**, using test suite provider like TestCafe or NightWatch.